# block js execution until async request is completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I have a problem with prefetching resources for react app. I have a function which should fetch json resources and assign them to a object properties in a loop. The function should then return the object with jsons allready resolved, but instead of it returns the object with properties as unresolved promises.

Is it possible to stop executing js code until the promises are fullfiled so the function will return correct data ?

Yes, something like a synchronous request.

```
async function getJson (file, url) {

  const response = await fetch(`${url}/${file}.json`);
  const json = await response.json();

  return json;
}

async function getTranslations(files, url) {
    let r = {};

  files.map( (file, i) => {
    r[file] = await getJson(file, url);
  });

  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using 'map' like that - to populate an object you're better with forEach. Though I couldn't guarantee that's the issue.

```
async function getTranslations(files, url) {
    let r = {};

    files.forEach(file => r[file] = await getJson(file, url));

    return r;
```

}